# How to define a binary variable in docplex?

Tags: python, docplex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frB75.png)

> y_kl = 1, if part k precedes part l in the processing sequence;
> otherwise y_kl = 0 (sequencing variable)

I have defined the binary variable y as:

```
y1 = [(k,l) for k in range(K) for l in range(K)]
y = m.binary_var_dict(y1, name="y")
```

However, idk if it is correct since k<l, how to add it?